# Using second menu?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to implement in my sudoku app a second menu but in the emulator is does not start. It says:

```
[2012-04-01 17:43:44 - Sudoku] Android Launch!
[2012-04-01 17:43:44 - Sudoku] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-01 17:43:44 - Sudoku] Performing org.madmax.sudoku.SudokuActivity activity launch
[2012-04-01 17:43:44 - Sudoku] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'em22'
[2012-04-01 17:43:46 - Sudoku] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-04-01 17:43:46 - Sudoku] Starting activity org.madmax.sudoku.SudokuActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-04-01 17:43:47 - Sudoku] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.madmax.sudoku/.SudokuActivity }
[2012-04-01 17:43:47 - Sudoku] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

and here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    //more buttons go here!!!
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One closed the application relaunch it this must solve your problem. Its because your application is not closed before relaunch

also replace these line

addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

with

setContentView(R.xml.settings);

Comment: kk I closed the app in the emulator but all it does is is shows the menu, but not goes to the menu. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: i didnt get you can you be more specific

Comment: I have defined a settings.xml file where I have two checkboxes. I call this *.xml with my Prefs Methode. But it does not show anything...

Comment: what is the error you are getting and code for prefs class and xml file yuo used

Comment: btw do you know a good method to debug my app, for finding bugs like that?